# I'm facing errors in terminal after typing npx react-native init AwesomeProject on arch linux

Tags: react-native

```
[hassan@arch ~]$ npx react-native init Test
Need to install the following packages:
  react-native@0.69.4
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/hassan/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/metro-source-map
npm ERR! dest /home/hassan/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.metro-source-map-rnpcIOap
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/hassan/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/metro-source-map' -> '/home/hassan/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/.metro-source-map-rnpcIOap'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hassan/.npm/_logs/2022-08-19T10_50_05_222Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: It seems a permission issue, the command trying to move temporary folder `/home/hassan/.npm/_npx/7930a8670f922cdb/node_modules/metro-source-map`
You could use `sudo` with `npx` or check your account permissions. in last try you could remove that folder.

Answer (score -1):

you have to check you node and npm is working fine or not. you can check their version or can install them again. May this will help you.
you can also use sudo command like

```
sudo npx react-native init textProject
```